# Upper bound for mean of squared variable

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, covariance

Assume we have two random variables $x \sim (\mu_x, \sigma_x^2)$ and $y \sim (\mu_y, \sigma_y^2)$ and covariance $\sigma_{xy}$. I was wondering if there is a way to find an upper bound to $\mathbb{E}(x^2y^2)$? I know that I have $\mathbb{E}(xy) = \sigma_{xy} + \mu_x\mu_y$, but I don't know how to find the upper bound for the mean of the squared product of the two variables.

Comment: I suspect that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent then it is possible construct examples where $\mathbb{E}(X^2Y^2)$ is infinite for any $\mu_X,\mu_Y,\sigma^2_X,\sigma^2_Y, \sigma_{X,Y}$

Comment: Interesting! I couldn't see that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's denote $X = \frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y^2}\cdot Y + Z$ where $Z$ is a random variable indepenent to $Y$ that will be determined. It's easy to verify that $Cov(X,Y)= \frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y^2}\cdot Cov(Y,Y)= \sigma_{XY}$.

We will determine the expectation and variance of $Z$:

$$\mu_X = \frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y^2}\cdot \mu_Y + \mu_Z \implies \mu_Z =\mu_X - \frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y^2}\cdot \mu_Y \tag{1}$$
$$\sigma_X^2 = \frac{\sigma_{XY}^2}{\sigma_Y^4}\cdot \sigma_Y^2 + \sigma_Z^2 \implies \sigma_Z^2 = \sigma_X^2 - \frac{\sigma_{XY}^2}{\sigma_Y^2} \tag{2}$$

Now, we compute $\mathbb{E}(X^2Y^2)$:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X^2Y^2) &= \mathbb{E}\left(\left( \frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y^2}\cdot Y + Z \right)^2 Y^2 \right) \\
& = \mathbb{E}\left( \frac{\sigma_{XY}^2}{\sigma_Y^4}\cdot Y^4 + 2\frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y^2} Y^3Z + Z^2Y^2  \right) \\
& = \frac{\sigma_{XY}^2}{\sigma_Y^4}\mathbb{E}\left(  Y^4\right)   + 2\frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y^2} \mathbb{E}(Y^3)\mu_Z + \sigma_Z^2 \sigma_Y^2   \\
\mathbb{E}(X^2Y^2)&= \frac{\sigma_{XY}^2}{\sigma_Y^4}\color{red}{\mathbb{E}\left(  Y^4\right)}   + 2\frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y^2} \left(\mu_X - \frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y^2}\mu_Y \right)\color{red}{\mathbb{E}(Y^3)} + \sigma_Y^2 \left(\sigma_X^2 - \frac{\sigma_{XY}^2}{\sigma_Y^2}   \right)  
\end{align}$$

It is **impossible** to determine the range of $\mathbb{E}\left(  Y^4\right)$ and $\mathbb{E}\left(  Y^3\right)$ (the two red terms) from the expectations, variances and covariance of $X,Y$ **only**. In particular, with the given information, it is **impossible** to determine the maximum (or upper bound) of $\mathbb{E}(X^2Y^2)$.

However, if you know the range of $\mathbb{E}\left(  Y^4\right)$ **and** $\mathbb{E}\left(  Y^3\right)$  (or the range of $\mathbb{E}\left(  X^4\right)$ **and** $\mathbb{E}\left(  X^3\right)$ ), you can determine easily the bounds of $\mathbb{E}(X^2Y^2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you also give me a hint on how to compute E(x^4) when the distribution of x is not normal? Thanks!

Comment: @MohammadHusseinYoosefianNoo You should have information about $X$, for example the density function $f_X(x)$ or something equivalent. If so, it suffices to compute $\mathbb{E}(X^4)$ by integration 
$$\mathbb{E}(X^4) = \int x^4 f_X(x) dx$$

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. Unfortunately, I don't have any more information (except for the mean and covariance). I am thinking about over-approximating the distribution with one in which x and y are not correlated. That is, consider a 0.95-confidence ellipsoid, I am thinking of finding the smallest circle encircling the ellipsoid. This way I'll have E(x^2 y^2) = E(x^2) E(y^2).

Comment: @MohammadHusseinYoosefianNoo In the initial question, you know $X,Y$ following normal distributions, right? The third comment is about another problem (that you only know the expectation, variance and covariance?), isn't it? Solutions highly depend on input information, so, it's very important to detail all input from the beginning.

Comment: No, in the original problem we only knew the mean and covariance, not the distribution. I am sorry if I caused any confusion by using ~ symbol.

Comment: @MohammadHusseinYoosefianNoo I write a new answer.